# If a NATO country starts a war, does the other NATO countries also enter the war

Tags: armed-conflict, nato

Ok, so I know that if a NATO country is attacked then so is all of the other NATO countries.  But if a NATO country decides to enter another war between two countries, aiding one side, Does the rest of NATO also enter said war. for example (hypothetically speaking) with the war between Russia and Ukraine, if a NATO country, lets say France (for example), decides to send troops to Ukraine to help fight Russia.  would France then be entering that war, and would the rest of NATO have to also join the war? Yes/No and Why?.  If No, then what if (again hypothetically speaking for example) would Russia see that as an act of war, and what if Russia then attacks France, Would the rest of NATO be obligated to join.